# Extruding along an area

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'd like to extrude a profile along the edge of an area. Furthermore, this profile should always stay in contact with the edges adjacent area.
Imagine a ribbon that twists. The resulting area(s) are where my profile should extrude along with.

Profile (orange)
[image]

Extrusion path (orange)
[image]

Edge of Profile (white) which is in permanent contact with the paths adjacent areas
[image]

End of profile (orange)
[image]

Thx in advance for every info on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate it using a Bezier curve.

1. Add a Bezier curve, and use the Tilt Tool to adjust the tilt.
2. Create the profile shape (It needs to be a curve too). The origin point position is important.
3. Set the profile shape as a Bevel for your curve. It will align based on it's origin point.

*Add a Bezier Curve and tilt the control points. Add more control points if needed.*

[image]

*Create the profile shape and set it as a Bevel object. If it's a mesh object, you'll have to convert it first.*

[image]

Comment: Wow thx so much. Can finally continue my work. :)

Comment: Happy to help :). If you get lost somewhere, feel free to ask. Good luck.